# How does Maven know where to put the source file under the exploded directory?

Tags: java, maven

I am learning maven , though worked on ant in past.

I have am just trying to figure out what happens when command `mvn install or mvn compile` is executed. I am mainly
interested how project is built like location of resources to pick for build and where to put them once built

My project source structure is

```
src > main > java > java files
src > main > resources > reources like spring config atc
src > main > webapp > static files like js,css etc
src > main > webapp > WEB-INF > web.xml and jsp files
```

Once i give mvn package or mvn clean i see below exploded directory(my focus is on this) with name myProject
alongwith other  files lile war, classes etc. Explode structure for myProject is

```
1) All files from (src > main > webapp) including WEB-INF gets copied under myProject
2) All files from (src > main > resources) gets copied under myProject > WEB-INF/Classes
3) All files from (src > main > java) gets copied under myProject > WEB-INF/Classes
```

As per my understanding when we give any of mvn install or mvn compile or mvn package
all compile phases gets executed. **But My question is how Maven know where to put the source file under exploded directory. 
Is it a standard maven follows?**

Here is snippet for reference from pom.xml i am using

```
<artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myProject</name>
.....

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exploded</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <overlays>

                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jslint</goal>
                            <goal>compress</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregations>
                    </aggregations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven follow [Java standard](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html) when it put compiled files in `WEB-INF/classes`.

> [Illustration from the The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html)

[image]

This directory contains server-side classes: servlets, utility classes, and JavaBeans components. These classes are only visible to the servlet and are not public.

From [Java Servlet 3.1 specifications](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) :

> 10.5 Directory Structure
>
> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named “
> WEB-INF
> ”. This
> directory contains all things related to the application that aren’t in the document
> root of the application. Most of the
> WEB-INF
> node is not part of the public document
> tree of the application. Except for static resources and JSPs packaged in the
> META-
> INF/resources
> of a JAR file that resides in the
> WEB-INF/lib
> directory, no other
> files contained in the
> WEB-INF
> directory may be served di
> rectly to a cl
> ient by the
> container. However, the contents of the
> WEB-INF
> directory are visible to servlet code
> using the
> getResource
> and
> getResourceAsStream
> method calls on the
> ServletContext
> , and may be exposed using the
> RequestDispatcher
> calls. Hence, if
> the Application Developer needs access, from
> servlet code, to application specific
> configuration information that he does not wish to be exposed directly to the Web
> client, he may place it under this directory.

Comment: Thanx alain. Two clarification on point 10.5 . First:- I know client can not access any file under WEB-INF folder. But looks like from point 10.5
that it is possible fot static resources and jsps provided its under WEB-INF/lib/META- INF/resources. Right?

Comment: Second :- 10.5 says "However, the contents of the WEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code using the getResource and 
getResourceAsStream method calls on the ServletContext ". My understanding is servlets lying under WEB-INF/classes can access
any class/resource under WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib folder without any difficulty. Then why it is said here "servlet code can access the 
contents of the WEB-INF directory using the getResource and getResourceAsStream method calls on the ServletContext" ?

Comment: @MSach For the first point, yes you're right but the exception is not on `WEB-INF/lib/META- INF/resources`but on META-
INF/resources
of a JAR file that resides in the
WEB-INF/lib. That is not exactly the same thing, you missed the JAR. For the second point the spec just specify how it should be accessed. Even if it's true that your servlet can access everything under WEB-INF/classes, you should use these methods or you'll encounter issues after packaging your app (in a war or ear for exemple).

Comment: Thanks your right. I missed jar.Correct statement will be "it is possible for client to access static resources and jsps provided its under WEB-INF/lib/META- INF/resources". For second point i am still confused  why i will encounter issues after packaging your app.  Servlets are also the java classess and if they are lying also under WEB-INF/classes along with other classes, why developer meed to use special methods like getResource and getResourceAsStream to access any class or resource ?

Comment: @MSach For exemple if you try to access an image using `new File()` or read a file using an InputStream, it won't work because the image/file are not on the file system but in the war or ear. Hence you have to use these methods to access them. This answer explain pretty well what is getResource() : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14089228/1140748

Comment: oh got you. It mean its true for any java class be it servlet or any service class

Comment: Yes, basically for all applications that need to be "portable". Even for a Swing desktop app you will have to use getResource to load images or whatever from the JAR.