# Unable to Read Text File in Java using FileReader and BufferedReader, possible reasons?

Tags: java, file, static-methods, filereader

Here From the `start()` method i called the `loadMap(filename)` method with a `text file`.But i don't know why though the loadMap() is called but the `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` doesn't working. and the text commented below this two File reader's Statement 
`System.out.print("INside loadMap()");` doesn't printing in the console and the text File isn't reading. What's the problem here occur actually? Help someone please.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DemoClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
    }

    public static void start() {
        try {
            System.out.print("Pobon File Inside");
            loadMap("data\\map1.txt");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    private static void loadMap(String filename) throws IOException {
        ArrayList lines = new ArrayList();

        FileReader fReader = new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
        System.out.print("INside loadMap()");

        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                reader.close();
                break;
            }
            if (!line.startsWith("!")) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        }
        System.out.print("INside loadMap()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, most likely you get an exception somewhere while trying to read your file(s). But this is exception is swallowed here: `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { // TODO: handle exception }`. Put a `e.printStacktrace()` into the catch block. And then tell us, what exception is written on the console.

Comment: Most likely it cannot open the file, and throws an exception

Comment: Did you try to provide absolute path of file?

Comment: it is not able to get the filename. can you debug and confirm?

Comment: i gave the `e.printStacktrace()` and it shows-->  `Insidejava.io.FileNotFoundException: data\map1.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at DemoClass.loadMap(DemoClass.java:25)
 at DemoClass.start(DemoClass.java:14)
 at DemoClass.main(DemoClass.java:8)`  this exceptions @Seelenvirtuose @13th Ghost

Comment: 1) Please don't add information as a comment. Go and _edit_ your question accordingly. 2) What do you think the error "FileNotFoundException: data\map1.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)" means?

Comment: This means system can't find the path specified. This program is taken from an `Applet`. The applet is working well and the File also uploading. I'm trying to convert that applet as an `Application program`. The given program is only a short demonstration of that program. So From the same  position and same path the `Applet` working but the `This` program is not. Why? @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: I've also put the text file in the same directory and called the loadMap() method like `loadMap("map1.txt")`. But same exception is showing. Why this happening actually? @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: I already asked you to put question-related information _into the question_ itself by simple _editing_ it. They are not comments! And the file `map1.txt` is not found in the _relative_ directory `data` (as you sepcified `data/map1.txt`) if the directory `data` simply is not inside the _current working directory_ of the program. So, if you really want our help, then please tell us the _absolute_ path of the file and the (absolute) _working directory_ of your program. You can also find something out by doing `System.out.println(new File("data1/map1.txt").getAbsolutePath())`

Comment: my `DemoClass` is inside default package and `src` folder contains `data` folder and `data` folder contains `map1.txt` file  that is `data/map1.txt`. @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: *sigh* And what is the _current working directory_ while running your program? Does it point to the `src` directory inside your project directory? Only then you can retrieve your file with the relative path `data/map1.txt`. Most likely the current working directory _is_ your project directory which does not contain a `data/map1.txt` but a `src/data/map1.txt`!

Comment: _current working directory_ is `src` and `src` contains `data` folder and `data` contains `map1.txt` file  that is `src/data/map1.txt` and `src/DemoClass.java` is _current directory_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `System.out.print("INside loadMap()")` is never called, then an IOException must be thrown when creating the `FileReader.`

In other words, the file you entered as the parameter when calling `loadMap()` (data\map1.txt) doesn't exist. You should consider retrieving the file in a different manner, such as placing it in a *source folder* and then calling [`getClass().getResource()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089146/file-loading-by-getclass-getresource)

Comment: But the `FileReader` constructor doesn't support `getClass().getResource()` URL . so how is it possible, can you explain please? @Nerdizzle

Comment: Don't use a `FileReader.` Use a `FileInputStream` as shown in the link provided.

Comment: so how can i read the file as `String` of text using `FileInputStream`? bcz i need to store them in a `ArrayList`. @Nerdizzle

Comment: Create an `InputStreamReader` by passing in the `FileInputStream` to the constructor, and then pass the instantiated `InputStreamReader` into the constructor of a `BufferedReader` like so: `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mFileInputStream));`