# What is alternative to getClass().getResourceAsStream() to get a File object?

Tags: java

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089146/file-loading-by-getclass-getresource) it is explained that *I shall always use getClass().getResourceAsStream()* so that I can read from jar, network. I shall not use getClass().getResource.toURI().toString(). So I guess, I shall not use getClass().getResource.getFile() or getClass().getResource.getPath() either for the same reason.

But what if I need to use File API (Apache Commons for example). I need to get a file from my resource folder (Eclipse) as File (or String, I can make new File(String)). What shall I do? Not use Apache Commons (say [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#method_summary).readlines(File), FileUtils.lineIterator(File) etc...)?

And **how shall I access a file from my resources folder writing code for a web app (which will be on application server as *.WAR = jar)?**

**Is it right. that I cannot use File API (Apache Commons FileUtils.readlines(File), etc)? Or there is a trick?**

Comment: Use `IOUtils` instead?

Comment: Perhaps it's best to explain the entirety of your problem, not just the part that you (think you) have solved. Why do you need to use the File API?

Comment: How would you be using this file object? Can we have a code sample?

Comment: Yes, don't use FileUtils with resources, they are not meant to be regular files.