# How to get file from resource?

Tags: java

I saved in the resource my font files *.ttf and I want to get it back when my application was started but I couldn't do this. I have the following code:

```
final URL fontUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/fonts/" + font);
                if (fontUrl == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                File fontFile = new File(fontUrl.getFile());
System.out.println(fontFile.exists());    // return false
System.out.println(fontFile.length());    // return 0
return fontFile;
```

How can I get a normal file from resource?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File loading by getClass().getResource()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089146/file-loading-by-getclass-getresource)

Comment: Your code is fine to me. Are you configuring the resource folder properly? Could you check the output folder to see if the file is there or not.

Comment: @NghiaDo I didn't configure the resource folder. How can I do it?

Comment: are you using maven based project?

Comment: @NghiaDo yes, I'm using maven based project.

Comment: Do you see your resource from target folder?

Comment: You can't: resources are embedded in the jar file, and not on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you placed in it assets folder? If you are looking forward to use it in TextView etc,:

```
  Typeface typeface = Utils.getTypeface(context, textStyle);
    if (typeface != null) setTypeface(typeface);
```

and the function in Utils file is:

```
public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, int textStyle) {
    try {
        String font = "fonts/font-file-name.ttf"
        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font);
        return myTypeface;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "OpenSansTextView init: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Location of my ttf file:

```
app\src\main\assets\fonts\font-file-name.ttf
```