# Loading and playing audio on desktop, and mobile with GraalVM

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to load and play an `AudioClip` in 2 scenarios:

1. On desktop during development (from an IDE) so that I can test that things work correctly during development.
2. On mobile, using Gluon's GraalVM native solution.

The media module is not supported on Android and [Attach's audio service](https://docs.gluonhq.com/attach/javadoc/latest/com.gluonhq.attach.audio/com/gluonhq/attach/audio/AudioService.html) is used instead.

What I tried: check if `AudioService` is present; if yes, load the sound and play it with the service; if not, load the sound and play it with Media.

- Is this the correct approach? I'm getting an exception as shown below.
- Do I (can I) exclude the media module dependency when I deploy to mobile because it is unusable?

Example classes:

```
package com.audioTest;

import static com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager.*;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.AppManager;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    AppManager appManager = AppManager.initialize();

    @Override
    public void init() {
        class HomeView extends View {
            
            HomeView() {
                var button = new Button("Play Sound");
                button.setOnAction(e -> Notifier.create());
                setCenter(button);
            }
        };

        appManager.addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, HomeView::new);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        appManager.start(stage);
        if (com.gluonhq.attach.util.Platform.isDesktop()) {
            stage.setHeight(600);
            stage.setWidth(360);
            stage.centerOnScreen();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.audioTest;

import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;

import com.gluonhq.attach.audio.Audio;
import com.gluonhq.attach.audio.AudioService;

public abstract sealed class Notifier {

    public static Notifier create() {
        return AudioService.create().<Notifier>map(MobileNotifier::new).orElseGet(DesktopNotifier::new);
    }

    private Notifier() {}

    private final static class MobileNotifier extends Notifier {

        private final Audio BEEP;

        private MobileNotifier(AudioService service) {
            BEEP = service.loadSound(getClass().getResource("/sounds/Beep.wav")).orElseThrow(); // throws here
            BEEP.play();
        }
    }

    private final static class DesktopNotifier extends Notifier {

        private static final AudioClip BEEP = new AudioClip(Notifier.class.getResource("/sounds/Beep.wav").toExternalForm());

        private DesktopNotifier() {
            BEEP.play();
        }
    }
}
```

The pom is the standard one given by the Gluon plugin with the added audio service and the resource list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.audioTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>AudioTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>AudioTest</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <javafx-maven-plugin-version>0.0.8</javafx-maven-plugin-version>
        <gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>1.0.14</gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>

        <java-version>17</java-version>
        <javafx-version>18.0.1</javafx-version>
        <charm-version>6.1.0</charm-version>
        <attach-version>4.0.14</attach-version>
    
        <main.class>com.audioTest.MyApplication</main.class>
        <app.identifier>${main.class}</app.identifier>
        <app.description>The AudioTest app</app.description>
        <package.type />
        <mac.app.store />
        <mac.signing.user.name />
        <bundle.version />
        <bundle.short.version />
        <version.code />
        <provided.keystore.path />
        <provided.keystore.password />
        <provided.key.alias />
        <provided.key.alias.password />
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>${charm-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>audio</artifactId>
            <version>${attach-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshot</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>snapshot</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${java-version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx-maven-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx-maven-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                        <list>audio</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <resourcesList>
                        <item>Beep.wav</item>
                    </resourcesList>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    <appIdentifier>${app.identifier}</appIdentifier>
                    <releaseConfiguration>
                        <vendor>Gluon</vendor>
                        <description>${app.description}</description>
                        <packageType>${package.type}</packageType>
                        <!-- for macOS/iOS -->
                        <macAppStore>${mac.app.store}</macAppStore>
                        <bundleShortVersion>${bundle.short.version}</bundleShortVersion>
                        <bundleVersion>${bundle.version}</bundleVersion>
                        <!-- for Android -->
                        <versionCode>${version.code}</versionCode>
                        <providedKeyStorePath>${provided.keystore.path}</providedKeyStorePath>
                        <providedKeyStorePassword>${provided.keystore.password}</providedKeyStorePassword>
                        <providedKeyAlias>${provided.key.alias}</providedKeyAlias>
                        <providedKeyAliasPassword>${provided.key.alias.password}</providedKeyAliasPassword>
                    </releaseConfiguration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>host</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mac</id>
            <properties>
                <package.type>pkg</package.type>
                <mac.app.store>false</mac.app.store>
                <bundle.version>${env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}</bundle.version>
                <bundle.short.version>1.0</bundle.short.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macstore</id>
            <properties>
                <package.type>pkg</package.type>
                <mac.app.store>true</mac.app.store>
                <bundle.version>1.${env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}</bundle.version>
                <bundle.short.version>1.6</bundle.short.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
                <bundle.version>${env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}</bundle.version>
                <bundle.short.version>1.0</bundle.short.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
                <app.identifier>com.audioTest</app.identifier>
                <version.code>${env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}</version.code>
                <provided.keystore.path>${env.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYSTOREPATH}</provided.keystore.path>
                <provided.keystore.password>${env.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}</provided.keystore.password>
                <provided.key.alias>${env.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYALIAS}</provided.key.alias>
                <provided.key.alias.password>${env.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYALIAS_PASSWORD}</provided.key.alias.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>pi</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>linux-aarch64</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The file is located under `src/main/resources/sounds/Beep.wav`.

The exception:

```
D/GraalCompiled( 7319): Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:377)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.audioTest.Notifier$MobileNotifier.<init>(Notifier.java:21)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.audioTest.Notifier.create(Notifier.java:11)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.audioTest.MyApplication$1HomeView.lambda$new$0(MyApplication.java:22)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8797)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:169)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonocleView.notifyMouse(MonocleView.java:116)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.notifyMouse(MouseInput.java:328)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MouseInput.lambda$postMouseEvent$3(MouseInput.java:241)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:704)
D/GraalCompiled( 7319):         at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:202)
```

Comment: You can always use the AudioService. Why do make this distinction? And what do you mean by "getResource is known to not work with JARs"?

Comment: On Android the AudioService should work just fine, did you add `wav` to the resourcesList? See https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_resourceslist .

Comment: @mipa According to Jose in the linked question, "Attach has Audio/Video services for iOS and Android (but not for desktop).", so I can't always use it.  As for the issue with loading resources from JARs, see for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089228/1803551.

Comment: You are right. In contrast to other Services there is indeed no desktop variant, which is a pitty and the resource loading problem is due to the fact that you can't use it as a stream, right?

Comment: @JoséPereda I didn't! What's the format for the list of extensions that I would add in `<resourcesList></resourcesList>`? I can't find it in the documentation. BTW, the first paragraph of https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/Resources.md cleared up some of the confusion I had with regards to resources in a native image.

Comment: @mipa I'm also using the Accelerometer, Magnetometer, and Position services, none of which have a desktop variant (which makes sense because they don't have the hardware), so from my perspective having a desktop impl is *not* the norm :) As for the resource, `getResourceAsStream`, which would work for JARs, would not help because I have nothing to do with an `InputStream` here (in contrast to `Image` loading, for example). Since I don't deploy as a JAR I don't really care, but I didn't know if a native image behaves more like my IDE or more like a JAR in this case.

Comment: try `<resourcesList><item>Beep.wav<item></resourcesList>`?

Comment: @JoséPereda I get an error from maven saying that I should have a closing `</item>`, and if I do that then I get a warning instead "Invalid plugin configuration: resourcesList".

Comment: just fix my typo :) 
`<resourcesList><item>Beep.wav</item></resourcesList>`.
Make sure you add it to the gluonfx plugin, inside `<configuration/>`

Comment: Or see this use case: https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/blob/gluonfx/DevoxxClientMobile/pom.xml#L272

Comment: @JoséPereda The warning I got was after fixing the typo, but that warning was because I pasted this under the `<configuration>` of `javafx-maven-plugin` and not `gluonfx-maven-plugin`... I will try again soon.

Comment: @JoséPereda Took me a while to set the build process locally (the process is not as simple as described) and not through GitHub actions, but now I can build faster and I have added an example case that shows the problem.

Comment: @JoséPereda If you have some time this week please have a look at this. Not being able to play sounds on Android is a blocker for us.

Comment: Not sure what do I need to look into? Last time I checked, AudioService was working perfectly fine on Android. Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: @JoséPereda I updated the question, but I also solved it. The resource list needed to include `<item>.*/Beep.wav$</item>`. Just putting the path `<item>/sounds/Beep.wav</item>` did not work. I think that the format of what goes into `<item>` should be clearer in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fine approach. There is no need to change anything in the Media module dependency as it will not be used on mobile where the Attach service is available.

For every resource that is not [automatically supported](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_resourceslist), it needs to be declared in the `<resourceList>`, and this is also where the error comes from. it requires a path to be specified, and just specifying `<item>Beep.wav</item>` will work only if the file is directly under the `resources` folder. To find the file, this pattern needs to be used: `<item>.*/Beep.wav$</item>`.

Sources: https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/Resources.md